# Changing android number locale

Tags: java, android, locale

I successfully added multiple locales to my app and figured out how to switch between them, but the problem is after I switch the locale everything works all right except numbers

For example if I switch to Persian numbers will remain **123** which is wrong and should be switched to **١٢٣**.

I can't use `String.format(number)` cause most of my numbers are included in Strings. Anyone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found is a hacky way to force a numeral font in Persian/Arabic locales!
You have to create multiple `font.xml` files and put them in `res/font` then use locale based `themes` to assign related font to `android:fontFamily`.
Here is the result:

```
font/font-en.xml
font/font-ar.xml
font/font-fa.xml
values-en/themes.xml
values-ar/themes.xml
values-fa/themes.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to translate number as well you must not bind it as a string , you must set it as float or int

```
<string name="numberRes">%d</string>
textview.setText(String.format(R.string.numberRes,numberValue))
```

numberValue must be an integer in case of float replace %d with %f

in case all numbers in string format use

```
    textview.setText(String.format(R.string.numberRes,Integer.valueOf(numberValue)))
```

and be careful of NumberFormatException if your string has a wrong number format

Comment: As I said most of my numbers are in Strings coming from server or user typing phone number/birthdate and stuff.

Comment: then I'd suggest checking the locale, and if it's persian do a regular expression to extract them/replace them. Something like `string.replace('1','?').replace('2','?')` etc